# How would I capitalize every letter of a name from an array in c++?

Tags: c++

When I try to compile my program says this" cannot convert âstd::stringâ to âintâ for argument â1â to âint toupper(int)â"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string names[10];

  for (int i=0;i<=9;i++){
    cout<<"Please enter name for student "<<i+1<<": ";
    cin>>names[i];
    }

for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
names[j]=toupper(names[j]);
cout<<names[j]<<endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believer toupper takes a char not an std::string. names[j] is an std::string.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a `char` to `std::toupper` not whole `string`:

```
for (auto &x : names)
  std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::toupper()` takes an `int`, but you are passing it a string. Do something like this:

```
for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
    for(int p = 0; p < names[j].length(); ++p){
        names[j][p]=toupper(names[j][p]);
    }
    cout<<names[j]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`toupper(int)` accepts only one letter, not the whole string. To capitalize whole string, you should write a function such as:

```
void ToUpperString(std::string& str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
    }
}
```

And then call it for each string that you want to capitalize:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
{
    ToUpperString(names[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this loop

```
for(int j=0;j<=9;j++){
names[j]=toupper(names[j]);
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) names[j][0] = toupper( names[j][0] );
```

In your loop names[j] returns an element of the array that is an object of type `std::string` while you need to gett access only to the first character of the object.

You could do the same the following way using the range-based for statement

```
for ( std::string &s : names ) s[0] = toupper( s[0] );
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can use **strupr** function:

```
char str[] = "sample text";
strupr( str );
cout << str; // will print SAMPLE TEXT
```